# rename qTip-2.0 into qTip2

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I was currently working on the [qtip-2.0](/questions/tagged/qtip-2.0) wiki entry, because i really like [this Plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/). But I do not like the tag with this Version 2.0 in the name. I think it is better to have [qtip2](/questions/tagged/qtip2) instead of [qtip-2.0](/questions/tagged/qtip-2.0). This is because qTip<sup>2</sup> is the offical writing of the Plugin and it is also easier to write.

So is it possible to rename this tag?

**Update**

Now i have the right to suggest a synonym as you can see here: [qtip2](/questions/tagged/qtip2) but because it isn't a highly used tag I do not think that anyone other has the right to vote, because 5 points in this tag are very hard to get... So in this case is it possible to do that by a moderator? It's the first time I suggest something so I do not know if my suggestion will fail into oblivion...